# Vectorizing the following for loop

Tags: matlab

I have a function that imports data collected in a txt file using the following code:

```
FILE = fopen(textDataFileName);

FIC = textscan(FILE, '%s');

FICu = FIC{1,1}(:,:);

n = numel(FICu); 

for i = 1:n
    FICun = str2double(FICu{i,1});
    FICa(i,1) = FICun;  
end
```

After the data is imported my function extracts all the necessary data and then I have other functions that do data analysis for me. My issue though, is that the function as a whole is slowed down by the above for loop. Originally the for loop wasn't a problem as the data set was relatively small; however, new data is appended to the text file everyday and thus the for loop has to contend with larger and larger data sets (the size of which cannot be predicted before importing). Does anyone have any easy way to vectorize my for loop and accomplish the same thing?

As a quick note, changing the format does not result in the behavior one would expect. In fact changing the formation to %f (for floating point) or %d (for decimal) causes the function to skip most of the data in the file.

Another update:

My code is now as follows:

```
FILE = fopen(textDataFileName);
FIC = textscan(FILE, '%s');
FICu = FIC{1,1}(:,:);

n = numel(FICu);
FICa = zeros(n,1); 
FICa = str2double(FICu(:,1));
```

This shaved 2s off the time it takes to complete. Any suggestions? (also, please note the issues of changing the file format, it did not work as one would expect.

Comment: i think using textscan with the right format (`%f` for floating point, `%d` for decimal integer) is the fastest option.

Comment: Matlab is be able to read binary files. I suggest to switch to a binary format (simple dump of doubles into a file).

Comment: Will changing the format make the loop run faster? Because I tic/toc-ed every section and everything is < .001 seconds except for the for loop which is up to 10.8 seconds.

Comment: You would get rid of `str2double()` in that loop. Also, see the comment of @Daniel R

Comment: All good suggestions. It could be slow because you're not pre-allocating. But, `str2double` accepts cell array inputs (something like `FICa = str2double(FICu(:,1))`) so I don't think a `for` loop is even needed if you still use that code.

Comment: I'm adding this to my post. But changing the format to %f or %d actually causes the function to SKIP almost all of the data and only imports the dates within the file.

Comment: What is the actual format of the file?  I don't think Daniel R was suggesting you just change %s to %f or %d -  appropriate format may be something like '%s %f %f %d' depending on what your file looks like.

Comment: The file is a .txt file consisting of thousands of rows of time stamped data. For example, one line of data might look as follows:

2256486.2 where the numbers before the decimal is the time and the number after the decimal denotes the event.

Additionally, there is a string that denotes the experiment, in this case it reads: FI_30_train